# Notification doesn't disappear on iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Although I have read all the message, the red notification doesn't disappear. It is there until I open this bug report.

- App Version: 1.4.0.234
- Device: iPad2,2
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

Comment: I'm hoping this issue has resolved by now.  There were some issues with the inbox refactoring that have hopefully been resolved.

Comment: @BrianNickel thought you will never answer. I think it solved.